# Angularjs http request doesn't go in errorCallback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, error-handling

I'm using angularjs to call my Rest web services but I have a problem with error handle.
This is one of my http calls:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "tr"+licenseSelected,//angular need string in url
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data : updatedLicense,
    beforeSend: function() {
        waitingModal.showPleaseWait();
    },
    complete: function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            waitingModal.hidePleaseWait();
        }, 1000);
    }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    if (response.data.success==true){   
        licenseTable.ajax.reload();
        $('#updateLicenseModal').modal("hide");
        notifyMessage(response.data.result, 'success');
    } else {
        notifyMessage(response.data.result, 'error');
    }                       
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    window.location.href = "/ATS/500";
});
```

I would like to show 500 page if an error occurred during http request (for example server down or wrong url), but errorCallback is never called.
Is there an error in my code? where is my fault?Thanks
This is an example of response that I can't handle in error code:

```
{
"status":422,
"exception":"org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException",
"message":"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"tr71\"",
"stacktrace":"org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"tr71\"
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78)    
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    ......"
}
```

Web service example

```
@Override
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/license"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Response createLicense(@RequestBody ClientLicenseForm clientLicenseForm) {
        try{
            administrationService.createLicense(clientLicenseForm);
            return new Response(true, true, "Your license has been created!", null);
        }catch(Exception e){
            ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
            LOG.error("Threw exception in AdministrationControllerImpl::createLicense :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
            return new Response(false,false,"Error! Your license hasn't been created!",errorResponse);
        }
    }
```

This may be the problem(it wrap json response inside another object), but how can I fix it?
[image]

***UPDATE***
I have fixed with this code, I'll test it

```
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (typeof response.data.success == 'undefined'){
                window.location.href = "/ATS/500";
            }else if (response.data.success==true){ 
                licenseTable.ajax.reload();
                $('#updateLicenseModal').modal("hide");
                notifyMessage(response.data.result, 'success');
            } else if(response.data.success==false) {
                notifyMessage(response.data.result, 'error');   
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            window.location.href = "/ATS/500";
        });
```

Comment: what error does it throw?

Comment: no error, it goes in successCallback

Comment: could you show your rest web service code?

Comment: I added a response of my web service. I have to go in error row only if server doesn't work or url is wrong, because otherwise I return a complex json with success field

Comment: i mean your backend code

Comment: can you pay attention to this: A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Note that if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it, meaning that the error callback will not be called for such responses. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: above status code is 422. I update with the cause, it wraps error in a response object

Answer (score 0):

Redarding you comments you get a json response (i think with 200 header)
The error callback will not fire while in the header response was 200 code.

You can manage it in two ways:

1. Rewrite backend side to return proper status header code
2. Check if response valid in successCallback

   ```
   if (response.data.exception) {
       window.location.href = "/ATS/500";
   }
   ```

**NOTE:** but basically it's wrong that server return this type or error with stacktrace.

[Exceptions handling examples](https://dzone.com/articles/exception-handling-spring-rest)

Comment: I have a communication with other system, so I use this message to give all details. As I have written I would like to use exception code only for error with server communication, like the json above where the status code is 422

Comment: @luca i am not sure that it's what you want..but seems you only need change this exceptions response to return http status code 500, for example.

Comment: @luca
with ResponseEntity you can do it like this, `return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);`